# How to open play-store inside an android app

Tags: android, google-play, app-store, google-play-services

I am trying to open a playstore link in a window inside my app (example in the image attached), but I cannot find a way to do it (except for opening the playstore app - and set mine to the background).

Tried to look at: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/packages - but no luck.

any suggestions?

[image: Playstore inside an-app]